# Multiple recursive union all selects in a CTE SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to build a query for searching all parent and children rows from a table using a CTE query.

I can either search for parents and return children or search for children and return parents but I can not handle both possibilities in the one query.

I can only complete one of the UNION ALL queries.

Where am I going wrong?

```
declare @search nvarchar(50)

--set @search = '%Nucleus sub project%';
set @search = '%Nucleus test';

WITH Parent AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM tblProjects 
    WHERE ProjNo LIKE @search 
       OR ProjDes LIKE @search

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tblProjects.* 
    FROM tblProjects  
    JOIN Parent ON tblProjects.proID = Parent.ParentProjID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tblProjects.* 
    FROM tblProjects  
    JOIN Parent ON tblProjects.ParentProjID = Parent.proID 
)
SELECT distinct * 
FROM Parent 
ORDER BY ParentProjID
```

I get an error :

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
`

Comment: You're selecting all the combinations of rows over and over again - it's an infinite loop, basically (just with recursion). If you want both descendants and ancestors, make one `with` for the descendants, another for the ancestors, and then `union all` those two :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using two different CTEs:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT p.*
    FROM tblProjects p
    WHERE  ProjNo LIKE @search OR ProjDes LIKE @search
   ),
   parents as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM x 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.* 
    FROM parents JOIN
         tblProjects p
         ON p.parentid= parents.proID
   ),
   children as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM x 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.* 
    FROM children JOIN
         tblProjects p
         ON children.parentid = p.proID
   )
SELECT distinct * 
FROM parents
UNION
SELECT distinct *
FROM children;
```

Answer (score 2):

The second select after the UNION ALL is called recursively until no more rows are added to the result set.

So;

1. You don't need the third SELECT statement. The second should catch everything.
2. If you have cycles (eg, the parent of A is B; the parent of B is A) you'll get an infinite recursion, and SQL will quit after 100 iterations, giving you the max recursion error.

Detecting cycles is more complex, but can be done.